# How to reference mshtml.dll in a windows phone 8 project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, mshtml, trident

Based on [this article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trident_%28layout_engine%29), windows phone 8 has Trident (mshtml).

So, how can I add the reference to it in a WP8 project?

Comment: Do you just want a `WebBrowser`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.webbrowser(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Nope, i want to user IHTMLElement3 interface
(or something similar)

Comment: You've provided no information about what you're trying to do or even what programming language. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**. Remember that Windows Phone runs in a sandboxed environment and third-party applications do not get low-level access to system resources.